# [Android]ListView cuts TextView text

Tags: android, listview, layout, text, adapter

In my project I have an Activity with a ListView with a BaseAdapter that shows a custom item list layout.
This list item layout has a textview and his text is cut off if with more than one line.
The code that I have written is like this:

Activity's onCreate method:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
listaCompleta = new ArrayList<String>();
listaCompleta.add ("Item1");
listaCompleta.add ("Example text");
listaCompleta.add ("This is an example text for writing more than a line in the listview item row blablabla blablabla blablabla");
adapter = new BaseAdapter () {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listaCompleta.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listaCompleta.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return (long)position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout, null);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.testoItemList);
            tv1.setText(listaCompleta.get(position));

            return view;
        }

    };
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

item_list_layout.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/item_list_layout">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/testoItemList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxItemList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"/>
```

And checkbox_selector.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star"/>
```

I found online many post as mine but all without solution.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Means your rest text is cutout?

Comment: @MrSmith i can't, I haven't the reputation for posting image.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your TextView with this

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/testoItemList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: @quasiaffatto is it still cutting ?

Comment: Sorry, I retried your code adding the layout_weight for having the checkbox too and it works. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @quasiaffatto Glad you came out of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your layour_heigth in the text view and Linearlayout for wrap_content. If textview have more lines de container expand to adjust. I you choose match_parent the size of container set by the listview.

You change this line:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout, null);
```

for this:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout, parent,false);
```

or layout parameters are ignored.

This works fine

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Change

`android:layout_height="match_parent"` 
to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for example:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/testoItemList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```